# Selenium no such element exception

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors

Im trying to get this link

```
 <ul class="row">                     
    <li class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 episodeLink37027" data-lang-key="1" data-link-id="37027" data-link-target="/redirect/37027" data-external-embed="false">
        <div class="generateInlinePlayer">
            <a class="watchEpisode" itemprop="url" href="/redirect/37027" target="_blank">
                <i class="icon VOE" title="Hoster VOE"></i>
                <h4>VOE</h4>
                <div class="hosterSiteVideoButton">Video öffnen</div>
                    ...
```

I already tried:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("watchEpisode")
```

and

```
button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("a.watchEpisode")
```

I always get an no such element Exception. Are there other ways to get this element?

Comment: Did you check if the element is inside a frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```py
button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.watchEpisode")
```

or

```py
button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("watchEpisode")
```

Don't forget to add a delay / wait before accessing this element
**UPD**
I see no iframes there, but the locator can be improved.
Try this code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
 
CHROMEDRIVER = r"C:\Users\Nico\Desktop\automate_download\chromedriver.exe"
 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER)
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
 
driver.get("https://anicloud.io/anime/stream/attack-on-titan")
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@title="Staffel 1 Episode 1"]'))).click()

button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[not(contains(@style,'none'))]//i[@title='Hoster VOE']/..//div[@class='hosterSiteVideoButton']")))

actions.move_to_element(button).perform()
time.sleep(0.5)
#now you can click this element
button.click()
```

Comment: @Probhet tried both, didnt work. Still get the same "no such element" exception

Comment: Can you share a link to the web page?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm allowed to share here because the website is a regulatory grey area.

Comment: Can you share it with me directly thru my FB messenger?

Comment: sure how can I find you ?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100011831197069 my additional account

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, see if it works.

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='watchEpisode']")
```

Comment: still the same "no such element" exception

Comment: try adding some waits or thread sleep, possibly that might help. And as cruisepandey said use the Chrome Developer tools to verify if indeed the element is highlighted by the locators provided.

Answer (score 1):

probably you can try with this css selector :

```
div.generateInlinePlayer>a.watchEpisode
```

or this xpath:

```
//div[@class='generateInlinePlayer']//child::a[@class='watchEpisode']
```

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

to get the `href` you can try the below code :

**Code trial 1 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
val = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='generateInlinePlayer']//child::a[@class='watchEpisode']").get_attribute('href')
print(val)
```

**Code trial 2 :**

```
val = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='generateInlinePlayer']//child::a[@class='watchEpisode']"))).get_attribute('href')
print(val)
```

**Code trial 3 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='generateInlinePlayer']//child::a[@class='watchEpisode'])
val = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].value", button)
print(val)
```

**Code trial 4 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='generateInlinePlayer']//child::a[@class='watchEpisode']")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).perform()
print(button.get_attribute('href'))
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```